# Adjust table items to be in the same row and display vertical border

Tags: html, css

I have the following table with a square created as:

```css
.content .row {
  padding: 0;
}

table.borderless td,
table.borderless th {
  border: none;
}

.table-layout {
  table-layout: fixed;
}


.bordered-element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.bordered-element .col-md-6 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bordered-element p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.bordered-element p.highlighted {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3da3d3;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-layout borderless">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Test title</th>
                <th>Test 2</th>
                <th>Test 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="row bordered-element">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <p>B11111</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <p class="highlighted text text__alternate-text">AB</p>
                      <p class="highlighted text text__alternate-text">CD</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

I want to do three things:

1. Add vertical border and adjust first column to the content
   [image]
2. Align second column tags to the left and display them in the same row (if it fits)

[image]

How can I achieve that? I tried to adjust the content using Flex, but it did not take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove bootstrap classes since they interfere with your flex styles, also you could use more semantic HTML:

```css
body{
margin:10px !important;
}
.content .row {
  padding: 0;
}

table.borderless td,
table.borderless th {
  border: none;
}

.table-layout {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.bordered-element {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.bordered-element >* {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.bordered-element>:first-child {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.bordered-element>:last-child {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.bordered-element ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.bordered-element li {
  text-align:center;
  list-style:none;
  background-color: #3da3d3;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px;
  min-width: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table borderless">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Test title</th>
                <th>Test 2</th>
                <th>Test 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="bordered-element">
                    <div>
                      <label>
                        B11111
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">AB</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">CD</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>--------------</td>
                <td>--------------</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div class="bordered-element">
                    <div>
                      <label>
                        B11111
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">AB</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">CD</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">EF</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">HI</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">JK</li>
                      <li class="text text__alternate-text">LM</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```